# many to many relationship update data mvc .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship in .net core mvc, but I have no idea how to implement a edit view.

The models are
Studios

```
public class Studio
    {
        public int StudioID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<StudioAddress>StudioAddresses { get; set; }
    }
```

Addresses

```
public class Address
    {
        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public ICollection<StudioAddress> StudioAddresses { get; set; }
    }
```

StudioAddress

```
public class StudioAddress
    {        
        public int StudioID { get; set; }
        public Studio Studio { get; set; }
        public int? AddressID { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
```

My databasecontext

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StudioAddress>()
     .HasKey(sa => new { sa.StudioID, sa.AddressID });
modelBuilder.Entity<StudioAddress>()
     .HasOne(sa => sa.Studio)
     .WithMany(s => s.StudioAddresses)
     .HasForeignKey(sa => sa.StudioID);
modelBuilder.Entity<StudioAddress>()
     .HasOne(sa => sa.Address)
     .WithMany(a => a.StudioAddresses)
     .HasForeignKey(sa => sa.AddressID);
```

Now, I have created the edit Get method in my studioscontroller

```
 // get
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var studio = await _context.Studios
             .Include(s => s.StudioAddresses).ThenInclude(s => s.Address)
                 .Where(s => s.StudioID == id)
             .AsNoTracking()
             .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (studio == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(studio);
    }
```

But I have no idea how to update the related data for studio and address?
Bot are forms with textfields. The [original microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2) are confusing (they work with tickboxes) and weird methods to whitelist fields. Is there a simpler, more intuitive way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your model definition, you could try to design the Edit view and the Post method like below :

Here is the “Edit” view:

```
@model SOMVCDemo.Models.Studio

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Edit">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="StudioID" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">StudioAddresses</label>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    @{ int i = 0;}
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var StudioAddress in @Model.StudioAddresses)
                        {
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" name="studioAddresses[@i].AddressID" asp-for="@StudioAddress.AddressID" class="form-control" />
                                <input type="text" name="studioAddresses[@i].Address.Street" asp-for="@StudioAddress.Address.Street" class="form-control" />
                            </td>
                            i++;
                        }
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div>
   <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Here is the POST method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, Studio studio)
    {
        if (id != studio.StudioID)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var st = _context.Studios.FirstOrDefault(n => n.StudioID == studio.StudioID);
                st.Name = studio.Name;
                _context.Update(st);
                foreach(var i in studio.StudioAddresses)
                {
                    var address = _context.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(n=>n.AddressID == i.AddressID);
                    address.Street = i.Address.Street;
                    _context.Update(address);
                }
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!StudioExists(studio.StudioID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(studio);
    }
```